# Keep the state of an Object same in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In our application we are having a requirement that we need to make the entry in database of an object and then send it to the user to make the changes in the same. As shown in the below -:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addCompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addCompany(
        @ModelAttribute("company-entity") Company company,
        BindingResult result) {
    CompanyService companyService = (CompanyService) applicationContext
            .getBean("companyService");     
    companyService.saveVersionAsDraft(company, 1110);*/
    return new ModelAndView("success");
}

    //Delegate to addPage after making an entry in the database
@RequestMapping("/companyHome")
public ModelAndView showCompanyForm() {
    System.out.println("CompanyController.showContacts()");
    CompanyService companyService = (CompanyService) applicationContext
            .getBean("companyService");
    CommonService commonService = (CommonService) applicationContext.getBean("commonService");
    Company company = (Company) companyService.addNew(new Company(), 1100);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("company");
    modelAndView.addObject("companyCategories",
             companyService
                .findAllCompanyCategories());
    modelAndView.addObject("sectors", commonService.findAllSectors());

    modelAndView.addObject("companyStatus",
            companyService.findAllCompanyStatuses());

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("company");
    modelAndView.addObject("company-entity",company);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

Now in this company object we are also passing primary Key of Db which we need to use in add Company() . So we need to return this primary Key with the object from the form.
Is there any way to do so ?
We are having 6 to 7 entries of this kind so we cant use hidden field in the form.

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What's sure is that you've not really understood what dependency injection was all about. You should not have calls to applicationContext.getBean() to get a service from a controller: it should be injected by Spring. Explain what you are trying to achieve with a concrete example.

Comment: Why can't you use hidden form fields while they remedy your problem perfectly?

Comment: Your `showCompanyForm` is also flawed, you are constructing 2 ModelAndView objects. You ignore the first one, construct a new one (only add the company) and return it. Basically all your reference data is gone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like JB Nizet said, it seems you absolutely not make use of the core of Spring : the **Dependency Injection**. 
Instead of using a direct get of a service bean :

```
CompanyService companyService = (CompanyService) applicationContext
        .getBean("companyService");
```

You should let Spring inject it with someting like that in your controller :

```
@Autowired
private CompanyService companyService;
```

Besides that, about your question, you have three options to keep the id. The first solution use the classic way proposed by Spring to edit some domain object (inspired by the RestFull approach) :

```
//Delegate to addPage after making an entry in the database
@RequestMapping("/company/{id}")
public ModelAndView showCompany(@PathVariable("id") Long id,Model model) {
```

Using this you will always have the id in the url, so you will keep it.

The  second option is available if you take advantage of 'form' tags of Spring. You will just need to create a form:hidden field and give him the path="yourIdAttribute"

The third is similar but you have to create a standard input type="hidden" and then get it in your controller with someting like that :

```
public ModelAndView showCompany(@RequestParam(value="name_of_your_field") Long id,...)
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you need more details.